# deploying a wcf service web site

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-6

I am new to asp.net & IIS. Now I am deploying a web site with wcf service to IIS. The WCF service needs windows authentication, so i have used impersonate attribute in web.config.

But everytime I change my password, the web page is not served and it throws error.  I think it is basic, but I donno.

How I can fix this permanently? Do I need to setup a ASPNET account for website? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Windows account where the password doesn't expire and only has the rights needed for the service to operate. Nothing more. Depending on your needs this may need to be an Active Directory account.  Then modify the identity element in web.config to use this account to impersonate. [identity Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) shows how the username and password can be encrypted and stored in the registry.